# Issue on bash script (quote issue?) smbclient command not found?

Tags: bash, shell, samba

I am trying to make a script to download a folder/file via a samba server and then to move it to the desired directory. I did this (script attached)
but the commands are not interpreted correctly ...

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# script client side to download files throught samba server

# Packages requirements: smbclient

# assuming locals ip are like: 192.168.1.XX
# assuming samba share folder's name is: "jean"

# @author: Jean 
# @param: last numbers of local ip @, i.e: xxx.xxx.x.01 ; -->01<--

# variable
SRC="192.168.1."    # local ip @ where samba is enable
NAME="jean"         # samba's group name
PASS="jean%jeann"        # samba's username and password

# *** test
CMD1="'tarmode'"
CMD2="'recurse'"
CMD3="'prompt'"
CMD4="'ls'"
CMD5="'tarmode ; ls'"
# ***
CMDS="tarmode ; recurse ; prompt ; ls"

# fct usage de la commande
usage() {
    echo
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "./client-samba.sh <end of IP @> <folder's name> <destination>"
    echo
    echo "        i.e: ./client-samba 12 toDownloadFromSamba ~/Downloads/"
    echo
    exit 1
}

# fct de test si le répertoire de destination existe
destExists() {
    if [[ ! -d ${DEST} ]]; then
        echo "ERROR : le répertoire de destination n'existe pas"
        usage
    fi
}

copyFiles() {
    # ( echo "${CMD1}" ; "${CMD2}" ; "${CMD3}" ; "${CMD4}" ) | smbclient //${SRC}${IP}/${NAME} -U ${PASS} -c
    # ( echo "${CMD1}" & ls ) | smbclient //${SRC}${IP}/${NAME} -U ${PASS} -c
    DL="smbclient //${SRC}${IP}/${NAME} -U ${PASS} -c ${CMD5}"
    #DL="smbclient //${SRC}${IP}/${NAME} -U ${PASS}"
    echo ${DL}
    $(${DL})
    #mget ${SMBFOLDER} 
    exit 1
    # mv ${HOME}/${SMBFOLDER} ${DEST}
}

# on teste le nombre d'arguments
if [[ $# -ne 3 ]];then
    usage
else
    IP=$1
    SMBFOLDER=$2
    DEST=$3
    destExists
    copyFiles
fi
```

Here is the error that I get:

```sh
smbclient //192.168.1.34/jean -U jean%jeann -c 'tarmode ; ls'
./client-samba.sh: ligne 51: 'tarmode: : commande introuvable
```

I specify that when I execute the command by hand, it works very well ...

Could you help me please?

ps: i know i could do it via the command smbget but (I would like to solve my issue first)

Comment: I recommend not to put commands into variables.

Comment: it doesn't work anyway...

Comment: Putting commands (or lists of arguments to commands) in variables doesn't work; see [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want, what you programmed.
The line `$(${DL})` looks a bit strange.
This would run the string returned by the command in `${DL}`.

Additionally, my experience to prevent quoting problems is to use arrays in bash.
I expect, this will work:

```
CMD5="tarmode;ls"
DL=( smbclient //${SRC}${IP}/${NAME} -U ${PASS} -c "${CMD5}" )
${DL[@]}
```

No single quotes around the command and no whitespace!

Comment: thanks, i try doing what you said but ...

    `DL=( smbclient //${SRC}${IP}/${NAME} -U ${PASS} -c \'${CMD5}\' )
    echo ${DL[@]}
    ${DL[@]}

    # or trying to put commands directly
    DLD=( smbclient //${SRC}${IP}/${NAME} -U ${PASS} -c 'tarmode : ls' )
    ${DL[@]}
`
and the error is : (for both tests)

`'tarmode: command not found`
`'tarmode: command not found`

i don't understand why it doesn't works ...

Comment: NO, you did not. Remove the single quotes!

Comment: sorry i did with and without and without it execute only the first command not the second one (which is ls)
     (and on my first comment i did a mystake with ":" instead of ";" but it didn't change antything

Comment: The second command is executed if you remove the space before the `ls`

Comment: I'm sorry but no     `smbclient //192.168.1.34/jean -U jean%jeann -c tarmode ;ls`
`tarmode is now full, system, hidden, noreset, noverbose`
`tarmode is now full, system, hidden, noreset, noverbose`

thanks, !  had to remove ALL the spaces

Comment: it works now thanks ! but why if i copy and paste the command on the shell it works (with the spaces) and in this bash script it doesn't works ?

Comment: This you have to ask the developer of `smbclient`

Comment: And (again sorry) but if i want to add `mget ${SMBFOLDER}` at the end of the ${CMDS} I have the same error (with the spaces I think) so like that                     `CMDS="tarmode;recurse;prompt;mget ${SMBFOLDER} "` (even if I replace smbfolder by the folder's name) I got the error : `nothing to mget`

Comment: `mget` act very unusual on folders. Read the smbclient manual carefully. Better use `tar` to download folders.